# Как можно запустить сразу несколько окон терминала с командами?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, powershell, поиск-библиотек

Мне каждый раз при запуске проекта надо выполнить по две команды в трёх терминалах:

```
1: cd server -> yarn watch
2: cd server -> yarn dev
3: cd web -> yarn dev
```

Как можно это автоматизировать, чтобы "одной кнопкой" запускать сразу три окна терминала с командами? Есть ли какие-то макросы в VS Code, позволяющие это сделать?

Задумывался о том, чтобы создать `*.bat` файл и просто запускать отдельно три окна PowerShell, но они ведь не будут в VS Code отображаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "client": "yarn --cwd client start",
    "client:install": "yarn --cwd client",
    "client:build": "yarn --cwd client build",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
```

[image: concurrently]