# Как сделать автоматический push запрос для любого коллчиства репозиториев?

Tags: node.js, git, makefile

У меня есть 20 репозиториев, которые у меня находятся на github.

При написании кода изменения могу появиться в любом из них.

Как я могу автоматизировать процесс push, что бы в конце дня можно было автоматически все изменения запушить в удалённый репозиторий ?

В данный момент у меня прописанны комманды в package.json

```
"script":{
"git push all": "npm run all repo1 repo2 repo3 ... etc"
}
```

Но так не удобно отслеивать какие репозитории появились, а какие я отключил.

Comment: Может вам лучше посмотреть на монорепозитории? Как у eslint, babel и т.п.

Comment: У меня есть уже монорепозитории. Я их как раз и хочу объединить.
У меня каждый репозиторий это отдельный монорепозиторий(сервис).
Я их не хочу объединять потому что мне в проект ещё нужно будет добавить два проекта и могут из за этого появиться проблемы с зависимостями.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171043/2659 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1286200/2659

Comment: Вот мне ответили. Это то что мне надо. 
Там документации только много, вечером читать буду только.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670693/how-to-make-a-push-script-from-bash/670697#670697